# Fire extinguish(ing) systems

Tags: attributives

1. Fire extinguish systems
2. Fire extinguishing systems.

Can you tell me why #2 should be used instead #1? Or do you use the 1 as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Extinguish* is a verb, and in English it is very rare to use a verb as an 'attributive'; so <sup>∗</sup>*fire extinguish systems* is not a conventional construction.

- ADDED: I'm sure there must be instances in which the bare uninflected form of a verb is used attributively—it's hard to imagine that anything possible in English hasn't been realized at least once!—but off the top of my head I can't think of a single one, and I find no mention of the possibility in a quick examination of *CGEL*. There are a few attributive *phrases* in which a plain-form verb is the 'head': *carry-out food*, *pickup truck*, *no-fly zone*; but a phrase is not a verb. There are also verb-noun compounds like *playboy* and *swearword* and *workman*; but these are all pronounced with a distinct falling cadence which is easily distinguished from the level prosody of modifier + noun. Perhaps readers can supply a common example.

Attributive nouns, however, are very common; so in this sort of construction we use the gerund of the verb, the *-ing* form, which may act as a noun in many contexts.

---

<sup>∗</sup> before an utterance marks it as unacceptable.

Comment: Thanks. But you do have the usage of the first form, don't you? I can't remember the words. Can you explain further if you can think of some?

Comment: @JoeKim See my ADDED paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, a hyphen should be used to create a compound adjectival phrase.

The problem in this case is that the verb "extinguish" does not have a common noun form, so using the participle ("fire-extinguishing") is the best of a bad set of choices.

Note that "suppress" does have a common noun form, "suppression", and "a fire-suppression system" does sound natural.